# Request API with cookie fails in different javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, xmlhttprequest, fetch

I am not able to receive the resources from an API using different functions in javascript.

It works as follows:

In one tab of the browser I open the application webclient and receive a cookie for that domain:
[first_browser_tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVEYG.png)

In another tab I open a page of a different domain and using javascript I request the ressource from the API. It runs over a gateway which has the same domain as my endpoint:
[second_browser_tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVvBT.png)

The cookie is not sent in the request and for this reason I get an authentication error from the endpoint to my request.

I tried to send the request in different ways and it allways fails due to the endpoint authentication.
See the code:

**Using fetch**

```
const urlToApiFetch = 'https://app.apple.com/api';

fetch(urlToApiFetch, {
    method: "GET",
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer 12345",
        "x-api-key": "12345",
    }
})
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch ((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    });
```

**Using XMLHttpRequest**

```
const urlToApiXMLHttpRequest = 'https://app.apple.com/api';

let testUrl = urlToApiXMLHttpRequest;
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("get", testUrl, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer 12345");
xhr.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", "12345");
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(r) {
    console.log(r);
}
xhr.send();
```

**Using jQuery**

```
    const URL = "https://app.apple.com/api";
        $.ajax({
            url: URL,
            crossDomain: true,
            method: "GET",
            xhrFields: {
              withCredentials: true
            },
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer 12345",
                "x-api-key": "12345",
            }
        }).done(function(data, status){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
        }).fail(function(data, status){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(status);
        });
```

Does anyone have an idea on what is wrong? Why does the cookie is not sent?

Thanks a lot

Comment: how do you send the cookie from your back end?

Comment: Hello, I get the cookie as Secure Cookie, HTTP only which expires when the session is closed. Is this a reason, why the cookie is not sent? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue...

The response header was missing the parameter:
`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

More details here: https://javascript.info/fetch-crossorigin